# Parse all the XML files and convert them to one CSV file

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing

I am trying to write a code where it search all the XML files in directory then parse those XML and save some data to a CSV file. I have 50 plus XML files in that directory. Whenever I run my code a CSV file created but it only prints data of the last xml file. How can i print all the XML file's data to a CSV file?Please help
Here is my code :

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import csv
import os

def writeToCSV(frelation):
    csvfile = open('data.csv', 'w')
    fieldnames = ['sub', 'sup']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("predicate")
    for elem in relation:
        sub = elem.attributes['sub'].value
        for elem1 in elem.getElementsByTagName("sup"):
            sup = elem1.attributes['name'].value
            writer.writerow({'sub': sub, 'sup': sup})


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('data/frames'):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xml')):
            xmldoc = parse(os.path.join(root, file))
            frelation = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("frameset")[0]
            relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("predicate")
            writeToCSV(frelation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U are overwriting the same file again and again in the WriteToCSV , may be a little change as below:

```
def writeToCSV(frelation,file_id):
    csvfile = open('data'+str(file_id)+'.csv', 'w')
    fieldnames = ['sub', 'sup']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("predicate")
    for elem in relation:
        sub = elem.attributes['sub'].value
        for elem1 in elem.getElementsByTagName("sup"):
            sup = elem1.attributes['name'].value
            writer.writerow({'sub': sub, 'sup': sup})

file_id=1;
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('data/frames'):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xml')):
            xmldoc = parse(os.path.join(root, file))
            frelation = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("frameset")[0]
            relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("predicate")
            writeToCSV(frelation,file_id)
            file_id+=1
```

if you want only one CSV file, u need to open the file in append mode, a+ mode indicates create file if does not exist.:

```
def writeToCSV(frelation):
        csvfile = open('data.csv', 'a+')
        fieldnames = ['sub', 'sup']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        relation = frelation.getElementsByTagName("predicate")
        for elem in relation:
            sub = elem.attributes['sub'].value
            for elem1 in elem.getElementsByTagName("sup"):
                sup = elem1.attributes['name'].value
                writer.writerow({'sub': sub, 'sup': sup})
```

No changes required in other code.

Comment: Thank You so much! @Rehan Azher