# Merging a CSV file with an XML file using Python Pandas/ElementTree

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to merge two data files, one CSV and one XML, incorporating some filters to remove unnecessary data.

Both data sets are referring to the same item with a unique identifier "Name".

For example in the CSV file it looks like:

```
No  Name    X   Y   Z   L*  a*  b*  C*  h   R   G   B
1   Item 8kp395185-Standard A   9.37    8.66    5.68    35.32   9.94    13.38   16.67   53.39   75.43   52.24   31.4
2   Item 8kp395185-Standard B   6.44    6.1 6.11    29.67   7.13    1.79    7.35    14.13   48.9    38.11   35.57
3   Item 8kp395185-     3.18    2.74    2.02    18.96   10.56   7.12    12.74   33.98   27.68   15.89   7.9
4   Item 8KP373606-Standard A   9.44    8.72    5.72    35.45   9.95    13.41   16.7    53.42   75.88   52.59   31.7
5   Item 8KP373606-Standard B   6.49    6.15    6.15    29.8    7.12    1.84    7.36    14.46   49.28   38.45   35.84
6   Item 8KP373606-     2.83    2.52    1.97    17.99   8.54    5.85    10.35   34.4    23.64   14.98   8.02
```

I wish to output a new csv file with all columns present in the original CSV file but with only the last column "Percentage" in the XML file such that the "Name" of each item partially matches. As you can see from the code above, there are three entries under Name with the same code "8kp395185". Two of these entries have "Standard" written after them which are just to ensure everything is working correctly, the actual entry I want is the third entry. This will need to be filtered so that the Percentage from the XML File is only written next to this third entry(entry without Standard in the Name).

In the XML file there are two entry's for each sample. One has a MinL of 0 and one has a MinL of 30. I am only interested in having the Percentage from the MinL of 30.

The XML File is as follows:

```
<CustomResults>
    <Operation>
        <Result>
            <Name>8KP395185</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.35</MidL>
                <MidC>13.64</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.88%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>34.56</MidL>
                <MidC>16.50</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.12%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name> 8KP373606</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>16.24</MidL>
                <MidC>10.90</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.19%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>34.08</MidL>
                <MidC>15.57</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.81%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KP376661</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>16.24</MidL>
                <MidC>10.90</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.19%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>34.08</MidL>
                <MidC>15.57</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.81%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KP368206</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>16.24</MidL>
                <MidC>11.15</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.43%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.73</MidL>
                <MidC>15.22</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.57%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA156325</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>15.72</MidL>
                <MidC>10.47</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.61%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.75</MidL>
                <MidC>14.72</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.39%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA156325</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>15.72</MidL>
                <MidC>10.47</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.61%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.75</MidL>
                <MidC>14.72</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.39%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KP632263</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>15.72</MidL>
                <MidC>10.47</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.61%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.75</MidL>
                <MidC>14.72</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.39%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8IP160338</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KP464202</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA152000</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA158546</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA154321</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA158545</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA154481</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA152008</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KA151998</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>17.26</MidL>
                <MidC>10.74</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>98.70%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.18</MidL>
                <MidC>11.88</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>1.30%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Name>ITEM 8KP638735</Name>
            <Region>
                <MinL>0.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>15.62</MidL>
                <MidC>10.82</MidC>
                <MaxL>30.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>99.27%</Percentage>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <MinL>30.00</MinL>
                <MinC>0.00</MinC>
                <MidL>33.47</MidL>
                <MidC>15.59</MidC>
                <MaxL>60.00</MaxL>
                <MaxC>100.00</MaxC>
                <Percentage>0.73%</Percentage>
            </Region>
        </Result>
    </Operation>
</CustomResults>
```

So I believe this problem involves:
**Include CSV**
1) Importing Pandas (to work with Dataframes)
2) Reading the CSV
**Include XML**
3) Importing ElementTree (to convert XML file to Dataframe)
4) Parse the XML File
5) Using a loop function to get "Name" and "Percentage" for each iteration of the XML file to create a dataframe but filtering out MinL=0.

Merge files
6) Combine data sets using Name as the unique identifier and filtering out "Standard" in CSV entry's. This will need to be done using a partial match as not all of the name will be exactly equal in terms of casematch. But the code such as 8kp638735 will be an exact match, but may have Item or ITEM etc written before.

I am very much a beginner to coding and Python but have tried and successfully read the CSV File but have so far not managed to list the XML file contents.

CSV File:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    data = pd.read_csv("Test_Data.csv")
    display(data)
```

XML File:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('020219.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

dfcols = ['Name', 'Percentage']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

for i in tree.iter(tag='Result'):
    df = df.append(
        pd.Series([i.get('Name'), i.get('Perentage')], index=dfcols),
        ignore_index=True)
    df.head()
```

CSV File:

```
No  Name    X   Y   Z   L*  a*  b*  C*  h   R   G   B   
0   1   Item 8kp395185-Standard A   9.37    8.66    5.68    35.32   9.94    13.38   16.67   53.39   75.43   52.24   31.4
1   2   Item 8kp395185-Standard B   6.44    6.1 6.11    29.67   7.13    1.79    7.35    14.13   48.9    38.11   35.57
2   3   Item 8kp395185- 3.18    2.74    2.02    18.96   10.56   7.12    12.74   33.98   27.68   15.89   7.9
3   4   Item 8KP373606-Standard A   9.44    8.72    5.72    35.45   9.95    13.41   16.7    53.42   75.88   52.59   31.7
4   5   Item 8KP373606-Standard B   6.49    6.15    6.15    29.8    7.12    1.84    7.36    14.46   49.28   38.45   35.84
5   6   Item 8KP373606- 2.83    2.52    1.97    17.99   8.54    5.85    10.35   34.4    23.64   14.98   8.02
6   7   Item 8KP376661-Standard A   9.46    8.76    5.69    35.52   9.81    13.7    16.85   54.39   76.08   52.91   31.4
7   8   Item 8KP376661-Standard B   6.54    6.21    6.15    29.95   7   2.09    7.3 16.63   49.66   38.9    35.79
8   9   Item 8KP376661- 2.78    2.47    1.92    17.77   8.6 5.92    10.44   34.55   23.26   14.65   7.67
9   10  Item 8kp368206-Standard A   9.41    8.7 5.71    35.4    9.96    13.41   16.7    53.41   75.72   52.46   31.57
10  11  Item 8kp368206-Standard B   6.46    6.13    6.12    29.74   7.12    1.85    7.36    14.56   49.1    38.3    35.66
11  12  Item 8kp368206- 2.84    2.51    1.97    17.98   8.85    5.85    10.61   33.47   23.89   14.87   8.01
12  13  Item 8kp464207-Standard A   9.41    8.7 5.69    35.4    9.93    13.47   16.73   53.59   75.72   52.48   31.48
13  14  Item 8kp464207-Standard B   6.46    6.13    6.12    29.75   7.09    1.88    7.33    14.88   49.11   38.34   35.63
14  15  Item 8kp464207- 2.78    2.45    1.91    17.68   9.02    5.89    10.77   33.13   23.47   14.41   7.63
15  16  Item 8KA156325-Standard A   9.32    8.61    5.64    35.23   9.96    13.4    16.69   53.38   75.16   51.98   31.14
16  17  Item 8KA156325-Standard B   6.4 6.07    6.07    29.58   7.12    1.82    7.35    14.34   48.66   37.9    35.31
17  18  Item 8KA156325- 2.65    2.34    1.89    17.2    8.56    5.19    10.01   31.22   22.1    13.82   7.85
18  19  Item 8KP632263-Standard A   2.65    8.65    5.67    35.3    9.98    13.4    16.7    53.33   75.44   52.19   31.35
19  20  Item 8KP632263-Standard B   6.43    6.1 6.09    29.66   7.11    1.85    7.35    14.56   48.88   38.11   35.47
20  21  Item 8KP632263- 2.73    2.44    1.95    17.66   8.08    5.49    9.77    34.22   22.55   14.61   8.01
21  22  Item 8IP160338-Standard A   9.29    8.58    5.62    35.16   9.98    13.38   16.69   53.29   74.98   51.8    31.02
22  23  Item 8IP160338-Standard B   6.38    6.05    6.05    29.54   7.11    1.82    7.34    14.36   48.52   37.81   35.21
23  24  Item 8IP160338- 3.15    2.82    2.26    19.31   8.5 5.61    10.18   33.42   26.21   16.95   9.97
24  25  Item 8KP464202-Standard A   9.31    8.6 5.64    35.21   9.97    13.38   16.68   53.31   75.13   51.94   31.14
25  26  Item 8KP464202-Standard B   6.4 6.06    6.06    29.57   7.13    1.82    7.35    14.31   48.63   37.87   35.29
26  27  Item 8KP464202- 2.74    2.42    1.88    17.53   8.98    5.91    10.75   33.34   23.15   14.21   7.43
27  28  Item 8KA152000-Standard A   9.33    8.62    5.65    35.25   9.98    13.39   16.7    53.31   75.26   52.03   31.21
28  29  Item 8KA152000-Standard B   6.41    6.07    6.08    29.6    7.13    1.82    7.35    14.3    48.72   37.95   35.37
29  30  Item 8KA152000- 2.78    2.51    2.02    17.98   7.69    5.38    9.38    34.99   22.8    15.18   8.52
30  31  Item 8KA158546-Standard A   9.33    8.63    5.65    35.25   9.96    13.4    16.69   53.38   75.26   52.06   31.22
31  32  Item 8KA158546-Standard B   6.4 6.07    6.07    29.59   7.12    1.82    7.35    14.34   48.69   37.93   35.34
32  33  Item 8KA158546- 2.48    2.33    2.06    17.12   5.6 3.56    6.63    32.43   19.29   14.38   9.64
33  34  ITEM 8KA154321-Standard A   9.35    8.63    5.66    35.27   9.99    13.38   16.7    53.24   75.33   52.07   31.29
34  35  ITEM 8KA154321-Standard B   6.41    6.08    6.08    29.61   7.14    1.81    7.36    14.24   48.75   37.97   35.4
35  36  ITEM 8KA154321- 2.75    2.46    2   17.75   8.2 5.16    9.69    32.15   22.8    14.68   8.51
36  37  ITEM 8KA158545-Standard A   9.39    8.69    5.67    35.38   9.91    13.54   16.78   53.82   75.66   52.45   31.3
37  38  ITEM 8KA158545-Standard B   6.48    6.15    6.12    29.78   7.05    1.94    7.32    15.38   49.19   38.45   35.62
38  39  ITEM 8KA158545- 2.51    2.37    2.1 17.3    5.39    3.51    6.43    33.05   19.43   14.69   9.93
39  40  ITEM 8KA154481-Standard A   9.35    8.64    5.67    35.29   9.95    13.39   16.68   53.36   75.36   52.16   31.33
40  41  ITEM 8KA154481-Standard B   6.42    6.08    6.08    29.62   7.13    1.82    7.36    14.31   48.78   38  35.41
41  42  ITEM 8KA154481- 2.52    2.35    2.02    17.23   6.08    4.09    7.32    33.93   19.91   14.43   9.13
42  43  ITEM 8KA154268-Standard A   9.35    8.64    5.67    35.28   9.98    13.37   16.68   53.26   75.35   52.12   31.34
43  44  ITEM 8KA154268-Standard B   6.42    6.08    6.08    29.62   7.13    1.82    7.36    14.33   48.78   38  35.41
44  45  ITEM 8KA154268- 2.92    2.64    2.05    18.56   7.72    6.12    9.86    38.42   24.01   16.06   8.34
45  46  ITEM 8KA152008-Standard A   9.42    8.72    5.69    35.43   9.9 13.54   16.77   53.84   75.82   52.59   31.43
46  47  ITEM 8KA152008-Standard B   6.49    6.16    6.14    29.82   7.07    1.94    7.33    15.35   49.31   38.54   35.72
47  48  ITEM 8KA152008- 2.76    2.53    2.05    18.04   7.07    5.17    8.76    36.2    22.32   15.41   8.81
48  49  ITEM 8KA151998-Standard A   9.4 8.69    5.68    35.39   9.92    13.53   16.77   53.75   75.7    52.47   31.36
49  50  ITEM 8KA151998-Standard B   6.48    6.15    6.13    29.79   7.08    1.93    7.34    15.27   49.24   38.45   35.65
50  51  ITEM 8KA151998- 2.91    2.63    2.05    18.48   8.01    5.96    9.98    36.65   24.1    15.85   8.45
51  52  ITEM 8KA151998-Standard A   9.36    8.65    5.67    35.3    9.96    13.4    16.7    53.36   75.43   52.2    31.35
52  53  ITEM 8KA151998-Standard B   6.43    6.1 6.1 29.66   7.13    1.82    7.36    14.33   48.89   38.09   35.51
53  54  ITEM 8KA151998- 2.92    2.62    2.06    18.47   8.1 5.9 10.02   36.09   24.16   15.81   8.51
54  55  ITEM 8KP638735-Standard A   9.31    8.6 5.65    35.21   9.98    13.34   16.66   53.22   75.12   51.93   31.2
55  56  ITEM 8KP638735-Standard B   6.38    6.05    6.06    29.54   7.12    1.79    7.34    14.09   48.54   37.81   35.28
56  57  ITEM 8KP638735- 2.72    2.41    1.86    17.49   8.77    5.94    10.59   34.13   22.87   14.2    7.33
```

This comes out as expected.

XML Output:

```
    Name Percentage
0   None       None
1   None       None
2   None       None
3   None       None
4   None       None
5   None       None
6   None       None
7   None       None
8   None       None
9   None       None
10  None       None
11  None       None
12  None       None
13  None       None
14  None       None
15  None       None
16  None       None
17  None       None
```

This returns None for entry's instead of the data. Also I have not included any filter to remove entrys with MinL=0 yet however once I can return a list of data I can look at filtering.

Comment: You need to convert XML file to CSV and then read both CSV file in Data Frame and concat both data frames.            Convert XML to CSV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787964/parse-all-the-xml-files-and-convert-them-to-one-csv-file

Comment: Thank you @Suraj for your kind response! I will look into this.
I believe my question is too large to have asked it like I did, I will perhaps repost and break it into chunks once I have understood Pandas & Python more.

I have found a nice Pandas cheat sheet: http://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf if anyone is new or hasn't seen it before. And also a nice overview of Pandas to look at for time being with some tutorials included https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html